# Issue with deleting all contents from table after transferring to another table

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-delete

Problem: in the file invoiceconfirm.php, at the end, there is a code to delete contents of a table(invoicesub), but it is not working. After all the calculations are done, all the contents of invoicesub table is transferred to displaybilling table. I wish to delete the invoicesub table as there is a calculation in the invoicesubitfinal page and if the same customer name is entered, it causes calculation errors. Thus, i need to delete the contents of invoicesub table.

Explanation on files: Invoice submit.php take in the name, quantity, amount, discount and customer name variable and then insert the into the table invoicesub. After that, it redirects to invoicesubmitfinal.

invoicesubmitfinal.php will just print out whatever is in the table of invoicesub and then add in a hidden fields which will parse the name, total amount and paid variable to the invoiceconfirm.php

Invoiceconfirm.php's purpose is to insert all the contents in invoicesub into a new table called displayoutstanding. However, i also want to delete all the contents from the invoicesub as well since if the same customer name is entered into the form, it will cause calculation errors in the total sum.

Invoicesubmit.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Process the form
    $name_array = $_POST['name'];
    $quantity_array = $_POST['quantity'];
    $amount_array = $_POST['amount'];
    $discount_array = $_POST['discount'];
    $cust_name_array = mysql_prep( $_POST['cust_name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++){
        $cust_name = $cust_name_array;
        $name = $name_array[$i];
        $quantity = $quantity_array[$i];
        $amount = $amount_array[$i];
        $discount = $discount_array[$i];
        $total_amt = ($amount - ($amount * ($discount / 100))) * $quantity;




            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $quantity . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$" . $amount . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $discount . "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$" . $total_amt . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO invoicesub (";
            $query.= " cust_name, description, quantity, amount, discount, total";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$cust_name}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total_amt}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


        }







           redirect_to("invoicesubmitfinal.php?cname=".urlencode($cust_name));

        }


?>
```

invoicesubmitfinal.php

```
 <?php
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Services Rendered</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Price($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

$cname = $_GET["cname"];

global $connection;

$sql1="SELECT description,quantity, amount, discount, total FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname' GROUP BY description ORDER BY id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['discount']. "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $rows['total']  . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";





          }    
          echo "</table>";     

          ?>






          <?php
          $sql1="SELECT SUM(total) as total_amt_2 FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>". "Total Amount: " ."$ ". $row['total_amt_2']  . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";

          $cname = $_GET["cname"];
          $sumtotal = $row['total_amt_2'];

          echo "<form action=\"invoiceconfirm.php\" method=\"POST\">";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"total_amt\" value=\"$sumtotal\" />";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"customer_name\" value=\"$cname\" />";
          echo "Customer Paid: "."$ ";
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"paid\" value=\"\"/>";
          echo "<br />";
          echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>";
          echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\" onclick=\"window.location='manage_content.php';\"/>";
          echo "</form>";

          }
          ?>
```

invoiceconfirm.php

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){




$totalsum = $_POST["total_amt"];
$custname = $_POST["customer_name"];
$paid = $_POST["paid"];
$today=date('d-m-Y');
$outstanding = $totalsum - $paid;

global $connection;
$query = "INSERT INTO displayoutstanding (";
$query.= " cust_name, date, paid, final_total, outstanding";
$query.= ") VALUES (";
$query.= " '{$custname}', '{$today}', {$paid}, {$totalsum}, {$outstanding}";
$query.= ")";

$finished = mysqli_query($connection, $query);




echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Services Rendered</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Price($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

global $connection;

$sql1="SELECT cust_name, description, quantity, amount, discount, total FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$custname' GROUP BY description ORDER BY id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['discount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$rows['total']  . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $custname = $rows['cust_name'];
            $name = $rows['description'];
            $today=date('d-m-Y');
            $quantity = $rows['quantity'];
            $amount = $rows['amount'];
            $discount = $rows['discount'];
            $total = $rows['total'];  

            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO displaybilling (";
            $query.= " cust_name, date, description, quantity, price, discount, total_amt";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$custname}', '{$today}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


              $query = "DELETE FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name = {$custname}";
  $delete = mysqli_query($connection, $query);





          }    

?>
```

Comment: `echo mysqli_error($connection);` after the delete query to see why it's not working. Also `echo $query;` and try the same on your phpMyAdmin.

Comment: your $custname is missing single quotes: ...WHERE cust_name = {$custname}";

Comment: No error messages were shown, in fact after checking, it seems that they did not parse the information to displaybilling table either nor delete the invoicesub table

Edit: Sorry i see the error now it's this :
Unknown column 'AlexSage' in 'where clause'Unknown column 'AlexSage' in 'where clause'

Comment: like @ICanHasCheezburger said, try to see if there are any mysql errors: $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

Comment: Still got the same error, where they say Unknown column 'AlexSageAce' in 'where clause'Unknown column 'AlexSageAce' in 'where clause' . AlexSageAce is the customer name field that i inputted.

Comment: Like @ReinderWit said, try adding single quotes in your `DELETE` query `as cust_name = '{$custname}'`

Comment: Okay, i fixed that. the delete part works now, however my displaybilling database seems to only run once, and it only inserted the variables once. 
Edit: I've also closed the while loop and put the delete function outside of the while loop, so it shouldn't affect the looping of the while loop

Comment: this is strange, since at that page it outputs 2 rows, why does it only insert once?

Comment: hard to say... you need to debug the code thats executed. Right before executing your insert statement, write out your $query and check if everything is as expected. Also, instead of just executing the query, put this: $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection)); This should output any error straight away

Comment: I did a echo $query right after the $result. what i got was :
INSERT INTO displaybilling ( customer_name, date, description, quantity, price, discount, total_amt) VALUES ( 'AlexSageAce', '04-03-2014', 'Examination and Consultation', 1, 10, 0, 10)INSERT INTO displaybilling ( customer_name, date, description, quantity, price, discount, total_amt) VALUES ( 'AlexSageAce', '04-03-2014', 'Radiograph: Intra-oral X-ray', 1, 10, 0, 10)

Comment: this is weird, it should be working in that case. what is going on?

Comment: Did you also put 'or die(mysqli_error($connection));' right after your mysqli_query()? This should output any errors during execution...

Comment: This is logically wrong, explanation - you have `customer name` repeating multiple times in your table. The `DELETE` query is deleting all the records of your customer at once and because of that your `INSERT` query has no more records to enter into `displaybilling`. You should use a unique id for each row in `invoicesub` to solve this.

Comment: **EDIT** Just saw your comment of `DELETE` query being put out of while. It should be fine this way, but try those two `INSERT` statements in your phpMyAdmin to see if they get inserted.

Comment: it wouldnt work, but when i delete the 2nd part, it worked? im puzzled.

Comment: seems like only one insert worked? But when i tried last time, it could insert both rows fine... hmmm this is strange

Comment: @user3340777 You mean only 1 insert worked in your phpMyAdmin? It would have thrown some error then, also it's necessary to have a unique ID/primaty column in each of your table, do you have them?

Comment: Yes my id in all tables are unique as well as auto_increment

Answer (score 0):

You get the unknown column error running the query because you miss the single quote in this query:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name = {$custname}";
```

should be:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name = '{$custname}'";
```

Also the {} brackets are useless here so it could be:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name = '$custname'";
```

You are saying that you want to delete the table. Are there other data in the invoicesub table more than the ones for this customer? If not you can consider to do

```
$query = "TRUNCATE invoicesub";
```

that will empty the table and reset all the counters to the default value.